# How to convert an xml to json without root in Python?

Tags: python, json, xml, python-3.x

I need to convert XML to json without root in python. Here is an example of XML

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <row>
    <Member_ID>926494</Member_ID>
    <First_Name>Corissa</First_Name>
    <Last_Name>Aguiler</Last_Name>
    <Gender>F</Gender>
    <Age>39</Age>
    <Height>5,3</Height>
    <Weight>130</Weight>
    <Hours_Sleep>8</Hours_Sleep>
    <Calories_Consumed>2501</Calories_Consumed>
    <Exercise_Calories_Burned>990</Exercise_Calories_Burned>
    <Date>9/11/2017</Date>
  </row>
</root>
```

I need to convert into JSON in the following format

```
   {
    "Member_ID": 926494,
    "First_Name": "Corissa",
    "Last_Name": "Aguiler",
    "Gender": "F",
    "Age": 39,
    "Height": "5,3",
    "Weight": 130,
    "Hours_Sleep": 8,
    "Calories_Consumed": 2501,
    "Exercise_Calories_Burned": 990,
    "Date": "9/11/2017"
  },
```

I am trying to use the parker convention from xmljson library but all the examples I'm finding are using string as input. I can't seem to figure out how to pass the actual .xml file instead of a string

For example:

```
from xmljson import parker, Parker
from xml.etree.ElementTree import fromstring
from json import dumps
dumps(parker.data(fromstring('<x><a>1</a><b>2</b></x>')))
'{"a": 1, "b": 2}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use standart [xml](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) library to parse it to dict and then dump dict to json if it needed:

```
xml_raw = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <row>
    <Member_ID>926494</Member_ID>
    <First_Name>Corissa</First_Name>
    <Last_Name>Aguiler</Last_Name>
    <Gender>F</Gender>
    <Age>39</Age>
    <Height>5,3</Height>
    <Weight>130</Weight>
    <Hours_Sleep>8</Hours_Sleep>
    <Calories_Consumed>2501</Calories_Consumed>
    <Exercise_Calories_Burned>990</Exercise_Calories_Burned>
    <Date>9/11/2017</Date>
  </row>
  <row>
    <Member_ID>926494</Member_ID>
    <First_Name>Corissa</First_Name>
    <Last_Name>Aguiler</Last_Name>
    <Gender>F</Gender>
    <Age>39</Age>
    <Height>5,3</Height>
    <Weight>130</Weight>
    <Hours_Sleep>8</Hours_Sleep>
    <Calories_Consumed>2501</Calories_Consumed>
    <Exercise_Calories_Burned>990</Exercise_Calories_Burned>
    <Date>9/11/2017</Date>
  </row>
</root>"""

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.fromstring(xml_raw)

xml_dict_list = list()
for row in root.findall('.//row'):
    xml_dict = dict()
    for item in row.findall('./*'):
        xml_dict[item.tag] = item.text
    xml_dict_list.append(xml_dict)

print('dict ->', xml_dict_list)
import json

json_str = json.dumps(xml_dict_list)
print('str ->', json_str)
```

OUTPUT:

```
dict -> [{'Member_ID': '926494', 'First_Name': 'Corissa', 'Last_Name': 'Aguiler', 'Gender': 'F', 'Age': '39', 'Height': '5,3', 'Weight': '130', 'Hours_Sleep': '8', 'Calories_Consumed': '2501', 'Exercise_Calories_Burned': '990', 'Date': '9/11/2017'}, {'Member_ID': '926494', 'First_Name': 'Corissa', 'Last_Name': 'Aguiler', 'Gender': 'F', 'Age': '39', 'Height': '5,3', 'Weight': '130', 'Hours_Sleep': '8', 'Calories_Consumed': '2501', 'Exercise_Calories_Burned': '990', 'Date': '9/11/2017'}]
str -> [{"Member_ID": "926494", "First_Name": "Corissa", "Last_Name": "Aguiler", "Gender": "F", "Age": "39", "Height": "5,3", "Weight": "130", "Hours_Sleep": "8", "Calories_Consumed": "2501", "Exercise_Calories_Burned": "990", "Date": "9/11/2017"}, {"Member_ID": "926494", "First_Name": "Corissa", "Last_Name": "Aguiler", "Gender": "F", "Age": "39", "Height": "5,3", "Weight": "130", "Hours_Sleep": "8", "Calories_Consumed": "2501", "Exercise_Calories_Burned": "990", "Date": "9/11/2017"}]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Just one more question, how can I iterate over more than one row. When I run this code, it only provides the value of the first row of the xml.

Comment: @SamirKhan `for row in root.findall('.//row'): ... for item in row.findall('./*'): ... `